# More efficient way to generate elements and associate $.data()? [jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, buffer, dom-manipulation

I'm looking for a more efficient way to generate some DOM changes and update the `.data()` object.

Presently, data is provided in an array of objects and I'm building the strings in sections, appending them to the table body, and adding the .data object onto the element.

Here's a snapshot.

```
for (i in data.users) {
    //Build the string
    var rowData = "<tr class=\"";
        rowData += (i%2) ? "odd":"even";
        rowData +="\">";
            rowData +="<td>";
            rowData +=data.users[i]["FirstName"];
            rowData +="</td>";
            rowData +="<td>";
            rowData +=data.users[i]["LastName"];
            rowData +="</td>";
            rowData +="<td>";
            rowData +=data.users[i]["UserName"];
            rowData +="</td>";
            //Could be many more columns
        rowData +="</tr>";

    //Change the DOM, add to the data object.
    $(rowData).appendTo("#list > table > tbody").data('ID', data.users[i]["ID"]);
}
```

I'm mostly upset over having to manipulate the DOM n times, rather than make one change with all the data-- or be able to release data as if there were a buffer. I would also like to update `.data()` all-at-once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.4.3+ you can just put a `data-XXX` attribute into a node. That is automatically picked by jQuery into the `data()` hash for that node.

```
var Buffer = [];
for (i in data.users) {
    //Build the string
    Buffer.push("<tr data-ID=\"" + data.users[i]["ID"] + "\" class=\"");
    Buffer.push((i%2) ? "odd":"even");
    Buffer.push("\">");
    Buffer.push("<td>");
    Buffer.push(data.users[i]["FirstName"]);
    Buffer.push("</td>");
          // and so forth
    Buffer.push("</tr>");        
}

$("#list > table > tbody").append(Buffer.join(''));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Solves both the issue of updating the DOM multiple times and the issue of associating data.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the data is coming from some server-side source somewhere. Why don't you using something like [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) in which you'll pass a JSON object (or XML or etc.) from your server (AKA, all manipulation is done server side) and then just display the data to the users. The graphs that [jqGrid generates](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) are very nice and you won't need to do all the work you are currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the jquery templates plugin .. still in beta but very nice!
http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for not putting that information in the DOM at all.  Use a JS model to manage that data, then query it as needed.  This keeps the DOM uncluttered and properly and efficiently separates semantic markup and the data that supports/drives it.  MVC ftw!